# GitHub versions for Arduino Library Manager

Tags: github, arduino, version, libraries

I built a library for manage library Arduino and it is now published.
https://github.com/ArsaLearn/Arsa-Main
And now I want to add the next version of my library, but when I add the new tag, it brings me the files of the previous version again...

Comment: Also asked at https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=712287

Comment: the library.properties with the right version number was added after tagging so it is not in the version. delete the release and the tag and create the release again

Answer (score 0):

Just summing things up.

You updated `library.properties` just fine, but there haven't been any other commits (apart from two test files) to your software since release 1.0.0.

You need to commit the changes you made in your software at home, especially the new files in the `src` directory, to Github before making a new release. You can't do that by just sending a new RAR-file; it will be ignored by the Arduino Library Manager.

How to commit changes, or sending updated source files, to Github is *basic* Git functionality and easily googled, and a useful skill to have. Maybe somebody feels like explaining how to do it in another answer; then again, maybe not.

If you somehow can't figure it out for yourself, the question you should be asking is *"How to commit changes in my software to Github before making a new release"*.

Comment: Can you guide me on this? "How to commit changes in my software to Github before making a new release".